# WP8 City lens immitation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gps, augmented-reality

I'm currently working on a weather baloon tracking app. I can already show the location on a map, but I also want a "city lens" kind of view. Example: http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news-700/Nokia-City-Lens-for-Windows-Phone-Sheds-Beta-Tag.png?1359725790

Is there any library that I can use?
I already experimented with GART (http://gart.codeplex.com/), but it does not take into account the altitude of the baloon. Everything is shown on the horizon, while I'm defenitely setting the ARItem.GeoLocation.Altitude property. Maybe the altitude is too big (>10000 meters)? Also the horizontal distance can be rather big (15 km).

Can somebody help me to get this work? Code examples would be very helpful.

Comment: having the same problem, I created an issue on their site https://gart.codeplex.com/workitem/10507